# How to pass command line arguments to atom-runner

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I am using atom-runner (https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner) to run inline my nodejs program.

Is it possible to pass a command line arg when using this plugin? Hitting Alt+R launches the node but since my script expects an argument, it fails.

How can I pass the command line argument before running?

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem to be possible with atom-runner as command lines expect the execution to be interactive. However, a workaround is possible with the below link:

https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner/issues/144